# How to enforce the Liskov substitution principle in Typescript

Tags: typescript, liskov-substitution-principle

The `compare` (overridden) methods have different signatures than their super's `compare`:

```js
abstract class Person {
  public abstract compare(that: Person): boolean;
}

class Student extends Person {
  constructor(private readonly maxGrade: number) { super(); }
  public override compare(that: Student) {
    return this.maxGrade > that.maxGrade;
  }
}

class Lawyer extends Person {
  constructor(private readonly yearlyIncome: number){ super(); }
  public override compare(that: Lawyer) {
    return this.yearlyIncome < that.yearlyIncome;
  }
}

// const s = new Student(96);
// const soul = new Lawyer(7400);
// console.log(s.compare(soul));
```

- This seems to violate the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56860/what-is-an-example-of-the-liskov-substitution-principle), but Typescript gives no error.
- Equivalent python code (below) gives an error.
- Only when I uncomment an actual comparison between a `Student` and a `Lawyer`, I get the desired error.
- Here is the python code + error message for completeness:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from abc import ABC
from abc import abstractmethod

import dataclasses

class Person(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def equals(self, other: Person) -> bool:
        ...

@dataclasses.dataclass
class Student(Person):
    max_grade: int

    # $ mypy main.py
    # main.py:22: error: Argument 1 of "equals" is incompatible with supertype "Person"; supertype defines the argument type as "Person"  [override]
    # main.py:22: note: This violates the Liskov substitution principle
    # main.py:22: note: See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#incompatible-overrides
    # Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
    def equals(self, other: Student) -> bool:
        return self.max_grade > other.max_grade

    # this works fine
    #def equals(self, other: Person) -> bool:
    #    if isinstance(other, Student):
    #        return self.max_grade > other.max_grade
    #    return False
```

Comment: A better example of the problem is if you assign a Student to a Person: https://tsplay.dev/Napxow However, "*Apply a sound or "provably correct" type system.*" is a non-goal to TS https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals

Comment: I dont see any reason it wouldnt work as it works now. LSP is nice, but you need to write and model it properly. And in JS we do not have OO, we have Prototype Inheritance, so the language will not be all OO paradigma compatibile with.